How to calculate time difference (in days) based on condition
I want to calculate the "days since baseline" for my longitudinal survey data, which is organized in a long data format, but I am having trouble grouping by participants' IDs. My data looks something like this:
Participant     Date
1               2023-04-19
1               2023-05-01 
1               2023-05-16
2               2023-11-04 
2               2023-11-14
3               2024-01-02
3               2024-01-15
3               2024-02-01

I would like to calculate the "days since baseline" for each participant. Something like this:
Participant     Date         Days since BL
1               2023-04-19      0
1               2023-05-01      12 
1               2023-05-16      27
2               2023-11-04      0
2               2023-11-14      10
3               2024-01-02      0
3               2024-01-15      14
3               2024-02-01      31

The code that I have tried using looked like this
df <- df %>%
group_by(Participant) %>%
mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format='%y/%m/%d')) %>%
mutate(DIFF=Date - lag(Date))

However, the calculated values are not correct and do not seem to be grouped by in a participant specific manner. I would like to be able to set the first date for each participant as their baseline (ie. 0) and then, for the following dates, the days from baseline are calculated based on each participants' own baseline dates.

Perhaps you want mutate(DIFF=Date - first(Date))?

It's unclear how your date format relates to the code: your code looks like it expects Date to look like "23/04/19" but in your example data it's already the standard YYYY-MM-DD. Perhaps that row not needed if you already have Date format data there.

Assuming the baseline date is the earliest date, you can do Date - min(Date) to get time since baseline. For example:
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
d = data.frame(Participant = rep(c("A","B","C"), each=3),
               Date = seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01") + 5, by="2 days") %>% 
                 format(., "%y/%m/%d"))

d %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format="%y/%m/%d")) %>% 
  group_by(Participant) %>% 
  mutate(DIFF = Date - min(Date))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#> # Groups:   Participant [3]
#>   Participant Date       DIFF  
#>   <chr>       <date>     <drtn>
#> 1 A           2023-01-01 0 days
#> 2 A           2023-01-03 2 days
#> 3 A           2023-01-05 4 days
#> 4 B           2023-01-01 0 days
#> 5 B           2023-01-03 2 days
#> 6 B           2023-01-05 4 days
#> 7 C           2023-01-01 0 days
#> 8 C           2023-01-03 2 days
#> 9 C           2023-01-05 4 days

Created on 2024-04-11 with reprex v2.1.0
